# Eclipse Plugin + Jython - Unhandled event loop exception

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jython

Just in case anybody else tries to use Jython inside a self-build eclipse-plug-in. I suffered 2 days on the following error, which occured as soon as I try to import my python scripts via `interpreter.exec("from myScript import *\n");`:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-12-11 11:22:53.549
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/eclipse/luna/../../../common/home/bel/schwinn/lnx/workspace-silecs/silecs-configuration/src/scripts/iecommon.py", line 6, in <module>
    from xml.dom import minidom
  File "/common/home/bel/schwinn/lnx/workspace-silecs/silecs-configuration/target/lib/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/xml/dom/__init__.py", line 226, in <module>
  File "/common/home/bel/schwinn/lnx/workspace-silecs/silecs-configuration/target/lib/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/xml/dom/MessageSource.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "/common/home/bel/schwinn/lnx/workspace-silecs/silecs-configuration/target/lib/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/xml/FtCore.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "/common/home/bel/schwinn/lnx/workspace-silecs/silecs-configuration/target/lib/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/xml/FtCore.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "/common/home/bel/schwinn/lnx/workspace-silecs/silecs-configuration/target/lib/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/gettext.py", line 58, in <module>
  File "/opt/eclipse/luna/../../../common/home/bel/schwinn/lnx/workspace-silecs/silecs-configuration/target/lib/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/posixpath.py", line 77, in join
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is needed to set the property `python.home` to some value. It looks like it does not even matter which value .. it just is not ok to leave it empty.
Setting the property e.g. can be done in the java-code:

```
    String jythonJarPath = "target/lib/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar";
    String pythonLibPath = SilecsUtils.findInBundle(jythonJarPath);
    Properties sysProps = System.getProperties();
    sysProps.setProperty("python.path", pythonLibPath + "/Lib");
    sysProps.setProperty("python.home", ".");
```